# Moving tabs in Komodo

Tags: tabs, komodo

There is no command for rearranging tabs in Editor in Key Bindings menu (moving a tab to the left or to the right). So is there a way to do it in Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to write two macros for moving tab to the left and to the right and set key bindings for them.

```
var tabs = document.getElementById("tabbed-view").tabs;
var current_tab = tabs.selectedItem;
var current_tab_index = tabs.getIndexOfItem(current_tab);
// var right_tab = tabs.getItemAtIndex(current_tab_index + 1);
var left_tab = tabs.getItemAtIndex(current_tab_index - 1);

if (left_tab /*right_tab*/) {
    tabs.insertBefore(current_tab /*right_tab*/, left_tab /*current_tab*/);
    tabs.scrollBoxObject.ensureElementIsVisible(current_tab);
}
```